# How do I get Chrome Local Overrides to work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools

In an Ember project I am trying to debug the error `index.js:903 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property onCancel of [object Object] which has only a getter`.
That has led me to `assets/@ember/~internals/utils/index.js:903` which I started to debug with breakpoints.
I gave up after realizing how many times this line is called. So I found out about Chromes Local Overrides and tried putting that line in a try-catch block with the catch having a debugger call.

I have reloaded the page with the overrides on and it acts like I never made the change.
I have also tried simply adding a `console.log` but that also does nothing.
I have also confirmed that this code gets called multiple times before encountering the error

Is there something that I might be doing wrong?

The file is saved and there is a file symbol with a purple circle on it.

[image]

Comment: Can't answer the original question, but I'd search for `onCancel` in the code and have a look at its setters etc. Ember ofter throws errors from some internal file (like in your case) and often it really doesn't worth to debug it. Just have a look at the message itselft and try to guess where this could come from.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I had noticed that while converting the Ember component to use the es6 class, I missed the action having the same name as the callback that was set on it.